# Flutter GetX stream value not changing when text field value changes

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-getx, bindservice

So, I'm trying to display a stream using a list view from a stream function, that takes an input from the text field.

```
Stream<List<UserModel>> queryByName(search) {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("users")
.orderBy("firstName")
.startAt([search]).endAt([search + '\uf8ff'])
.limit(10).snapshots()
 .map(userListFromQuerySnapshot); }
```

..

```
Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Obx(
            () => TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                _.search.value = text;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search keyword'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GetX<PalsViewController>(
          init: Get.put<PalsViewController>(PalsViewController()),
          builder: (PalsViewController palsViewController) {
            return Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: palsViewController.viewPals.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Row(children: [
                              palsViewController.viewPals[index]
                                          .profileImageUrl !=
                                      ''
                                  ? CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 20,
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                          palsViewController.viewPals[index]
                                              .profileImageUrl),
                                    )
                                  : Icon(Icons.person, size: 30),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Text(palsViewController
                                  .viewPals[index].firstName)
                            ])),
                        const Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
```

So, here's the issue.. the bind stream receives only the initial input of the search string which is empty.. and it's not changing when the text field value changes.

```
RxList<UserModel> viewPals = RxList<UserModel>([]);

var search = ''.obs ;

@override
 void onInit() {
 super.onInit();
 viewPals.bindStream(UserService.instance.queryByName(search.value));
}
```

Comment: Please, write your code instead of using screenshot.

Comment: Kindly wrap your textfield part in Obx.

Comment: @Maqsood, I just did that now, got improper use of GetX has been detected error

Comment: Wrap the column with Obx.

Comment: Same error @Maqsood.. Improper use of GetX has been detected.
I think the problem is from the bindStream, but I don't know what exactly..  It just uses the initial value but does update the textfield value onchanged, even when I can see the text field values change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this. hope it will help you resolve your bindStream issue.

```
Stream<List<UserModel>> queryByName(search) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .orderBy("firstName")
      .startAt([search]).endAt([search + '\uf8ff'])
      .limit(10).snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot query) {
    List<UserModel> retVal = [];
    query.docs.forEach((element) {
      retVal.add(UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));
    });
    return retVal;
  });
}
```

and in your onInit() use like this.

```
UserService.instance.queryByName(search.value).listen((event) {
   viewPals.assignAll(event);
});
```

and use viewPals like this.

```
var viewPals = <UserModel>[].obs;
```

use this as model class

```
class UserModel {
  String id;
   String bannerImageUrl;
   String profileImageUrl;
   String lastName;
   String firstName;
   String phoneNumber;
  UserModel(
      { this.id,
       this.bannerImageUrl,
       this.profileImageUrl,
       this.lastName,
       this.firstName,
       this.phoneNumber});

  UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot jsonMap) {
    try {
      id = jsonMap.id;
      bannerImageUrl = jsonMap.get('bannerImageUrl') != null ? jsonMap.get('bannerImageUrl').toString() : '';
      profileImageUrl = jsonMap.get('profileImageUrl') != null ? jsonMap.get('profileImageUrl') : '';
      lastName = jsonMap.get('lastName') != null ? jsonMap.get('lastName') : '';
      firstName = jsonMap.get('firstName') != null ? jsonMap.get('firstName') : '';
      phoneNumber = jsonMap.get('phoneNumber') != null ? jsonMap.get('phoneNumber') : '';
    } catch (e) {
      id = null;
      bannerImageUrl = '';
      profileImageUrl = '';
      lastName = '';
      firstName = 'null';
      phoneNumber = '';
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I got an error on line 9.. 
`retVal.add(UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));` 
saying .. The method 'fromDocumentSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'UserModel'.

Comment: can you plz provide you UserModel class

Comment: Here's what in my User Model  

`class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String bannerImageUrl;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final String lastName;
  final String firstName;
  final String phoneNumber;

  UserModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.bannerImageUrl,
      required this.profileImageUrl,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.firstName,
      required this.phoneNumber});

}`

Comment: added model class in my answer. kindly check it

Comment: Thanks again!  seen it.
It runs without any errors now.. it displays the users firstname, but the search functionality isn't working yet

Comment: Use TextEditingController in your texfield.

Comment: in your controller write this  TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245202/discussion-between-maqsood-and-michael-ogundipe).